# React Reload Componentes effect

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, web, frameworks, vite

recently I noticed an effect (I don't know if I should call it that) of some pages, pages like Facebook or Github, when they are reloaded they do not lose sight of the most main visual elements of the page, such as the logo on the Facebook page or the complete navbar on the github page, in the same way I don't know if it is due to the hosting, since in my projects with react when I reload the page the components are completely reloaded, until You can see the original color of the page (white) before it loads the one I have set.

In short, I don't know how to "save" the information in the browser or what type of modules or practices should be used to achieve this effect, likewise thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.